# RIP Harlan Ellison

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Harlan Ellison, author of many SFF works, passed away June 27, 2018, at the age of 84.

He had written a multitude of short stories and novels, as well as TV episodes such as "The City on the Edge of Forever" from *Star Trek*.

> For a brief time, I was here; and, for a brief time, I mattered.

> Like the wind crying endlessly through the universe, Time carries away the names and the deeds of conquerors and commoners alike. And all that we are, all that remains, is in the memories of those who cared we came this way for a brief moment.

Comment: I was surprised he was still alive! I thought all the great legends had died already...

Answer (score 15):

Harlan Ellison's fantastic writing will be greatly missed!

If *Babylon 5* is to be believed, we can still look forward to Harlan Ellison publishing his autobiography: *[Working Without a Net](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Working_Without_a_Net)*:

[image: Harlan Ellison autobiography]

> The book is Harlan's autobiography, which he plans to write around
>   the year 2000, and yes, that's his photo. (He borrowed the prop when we
>   were finished and casually carried it with him to a few places, just to
>   make people nuts thinking there was a book out they'd missed....)
>
> <sub>J. Michael Straczynski on Usenet, 9/3/1994 1:31:00 PM</sub>

Answer (score 11):

A little something I threw together..........[image]

Comment: it's funny that he would actually probably hate this lol

Comment: Or sue me for it.

Comment: But this is very apt -- if Ellison is remembered in the distant future, I think it will be as a writer for Star Trek. Imagine, ST:OS will almost certainly, if we manage to hold our civilization together, be watched in Star Trek times and I reflect on meeting a little kid that he will probably in turn meet someone someday who will live until the 23rd century -- kind of mind-boggling. I have already met people who met people from the 18th century (probably). That's a five hundred-year span.